# Google related bar - how to keep from showing up on my website

Tags: javascript

A new "google related" bar shows up at the bottom of my website.  It displays links to my competitors and other things like maps, etc.  It is tied in with users using the google toolbar.  If anyone has any ideas on how I can disable from displaying on my web side I would sure appreciate it.

Comment: Huh? Is your website hosted with a free service? If not, there's no way that should be there unless you put it there. It's probably put there by default b/c you aren't paying anything.

Comment: No.  It is part of the google toolbar i am guessing.  It shows up on most large sites i visit.  It is floating div that rises from the bottom a couple of seconds after full page load.  Here is a link to an explanation and screen capture. [link](http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2011/07/google-related.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from http://harrybailey.com/2011/08/hide-google-related-bar-on-your-website-with-css/

Google inserts an iframe into your html with the class .grelated-iframe

So hiding it is as simple as including the following css:

```
iframe.grelated-iframe {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Harry. I really appreciate the time.  Out of curiosity, how did you find out that it was an iframe and the name?

Comment: Hi Mike. There are various tools you can use to check. I use the Chrome browser and it's inspector tool to show the pages generated source. You can right click any element and 'inspect' it. It revealed an iframe with the class mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Google removed div and frame names and put everything to important so original answer no longer works on my site. We need to wait for the iframe to be created and then hide it by classname.  Couldn't get .delay to work, but this does...today anyway.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
setTimeout(function(){
$(‘.notranslate’).hide();},1000);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Following javascript code tries to find the google related iframe as soon as the window finishes loading. If found, it is made hidden, else an interval of one second is initialized, which checks for the specified iframe and makes it hidden as soon as it is found on page.

```
$(window).load(function (){
var giframe = null;
var giframecnt = 0;
var giframetmr = -1;

giframe = $("body > iframe.notranslate")[0];
if(giframe != null)
    $(giframe).css("display", "none");
else
    giframetmr = setInterval(function(){
        giframe = $("body > iframe.notranslate")[0];
        if(giframe != null) {
            clearInterval(giframetmr);
            $(giframe).css("display", "none");
        } else if(giframecnt >= 20)
            clearInterval(giframetmr);
        else
            giframecnt++;
    }, 1000);});
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the parent DIV element that contains the stuff in the bar. If it has an `id` or `name` attribute, *and* you can control the page CSS then simply add a rule for the element, i.e. if you see something like

```
<div id="footer-bar-div".....
```

then add a CSS rule

`#footer-bar-div {display:none ! important}`

This will not work if the bar is inside an `iframe` element, but even in that case you should be able to hide it using javascript, but you will need to find the name/id of the frame, i.e.:

```
var badFrame = document.getElementById('badFrameId').contentWindow;
badFrame.getElementById('footer-bar-div').style.display='none';
```

if the frame has a name, then instead you should access it with:

```
var badFrame = window.frames['badFrameName']
```

There is also a chance that the bar is generated on-the-fly using javascript. If it is added to the end of the page you can simply add a `<noscript>` tag at the end of your content - this will prevent the javascript from executing. This is an old trick so it might not always work.

Comment: Thanks ccpizza.  This doesn't seem to work yet, for me and I can't use the noscript option.  I can't seem to get the div name unfortunatly or else I think your approach would work.  Explanation of the bar is at this [link](http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2011/07/google-related.html)